# How to spy on a method called in a subscription inside ngOnInit in Angular test spec?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, spy

I need to test whether I have initialized my fields properly or not based on a property value. This property is used in a condition within a method called under a subscription called in the ngOnInit. I am using a spy to return a boolean as a mock value for this spec. The problem is that there is a delay between the call and the spyOn action and even though the spy change the value of the property, seems like it was not fast enough.

component.ts

```
//Value I want to test
value;

//This is the property I need to check
get isThisTrue() {
    return this.externalService.isTrue();
}

ngOnInit() {
this.otherService.getSomething().subscribe(res => {
  this.method();
   })
}

method() {
  if(this.isThisTrue) {
   this.value = 1;
  } else {
     this.value = 2;
}
```

component.spec.ts

```
//That is my failing test.
it('should be 2', inject([ExternalService], (service) => {
  spyOn(service, 'isTrue').and.returnValue(false);
  component.ngOnInit();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(value).toBe(2);
}))
```

ps.: If I force the result to be false inside the component the test passes.

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Comment: I just want to spy on a method call and return a value inside a subscription inside ngOnInit.

Comment: You need to execute it in async and call done or use any other method for tests where you have async behaviour.

Comment: I have tried that @Nanotron but the problem is that the method is been called inside the subscription. Usually the async approach helps when you want to await until you receive the fulfillment so you can work with it. The thing I don't care about what is being subscribed to, I only care about the method that was called inside. The spy is not working even when I use the async approaches

Comment: You probably need to mock/spy on that also then. For example, if that subscription was using http req, you would need to mock that. Your method will never get called. Have you debugged it at all? Put a breakpoint inside ngOnit and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem where the data returned by spyOn method was not being used in ngOnInit of the component.

The problem in my case was that the component was getting created in beforeEach() method

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges(); 
});
```

So, its ngOnInit() was also getting called immediately before spy method could return mock data.

I moved the code from beforeEach() method to a function createComponent()

```
function createComponent(){
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
 }
```

and called this function from the test spec after returning mock data using spyOn.

```
it('should create component with 2 rows', async () => {
    const expectedData: string[] = ['row 1', 'row 2'];
    myServiceSpy.getData.and.returnValue(expectedData));

    createComponent();

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(myServiceSpy.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component.data.length).toEqual(2);
    });
});

Now, the component is getting the mock data as expected
```

Comment: This answer helped me figure out my situation: I was trying to spyOn a component's method, which was called in ngOnInit. I am using the same setup, with the component being created in beforeEach, so the method was being called before I got the chance to place a spy on it. I am also using ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, so when I moved the component creation in the test (to bypass the auto change detection), it still didn't work, because change detection was still being run upon component creation. I had to comment CFAD and do a manual change detection for it to finally work.